# Jquery .next() - not compatible for ie 6+7? What should I use?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

jQuery `.next()` - not compatible for ie 6+7 (write warning in netbeans editor).

What option that work in ie6+ie7 exist in jQuery?

Delete edit because havy code

Thanks

Comment: DId you test this to get proof, or do you just believe what the editor says?

Comment: I have code that not working in ie6+ie7 but working in ie8 soo I try figure out why

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`next` works just fine in IE6 and IE7.

Example:

HTML:

```
<div id='container'>
  <div>Target A</div>
  <div>Target B</div>
  <div>Target C</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  $("#container div").click(function() {
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (next.length == 0) {
      display("There's no div after this one");
    }
    else {
      display("The next div's text is: " + next.text());
    }
  });

  function display(msg) {
    $("<p/>").html(msg).appendTo(document.body);
  }

});​
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/oluva4)

Tested and working in IE6 and IE7, both of which are on jQuery's [list of supported browsers](http://docs.jquery.com/Browser_Compatibility).

Comment: soo why netbeans write this warning? (jquery-ui rount borders not working in ie6,ie7).Maybe in othe rcase its not working? like li a

Comment: @Yosef: If the warning is about `next`, I have no idea. If the warning is about jQuery UI's "round borders" not working on IE6 and IE7 (which isn't what your question said), that's true. They don't work in IE8, either, because they rely on `border-radius` CSS, which IE doesn't support. Go to http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/, click Help in the box on the far left, and scroll down to "Browser Support Notice".

Comment: Just an observation to advance things. Take the example of a UL element with class A and another UL element inside with class B. The second UL happens to be display:none. According to a test done on an LI placed just before the .class B, the class of next returns as B on FF and A on IE7.

Comment: @JamesPoulson: Just so people reading don't get unnecessarily concerned: **In my experience, `next` is entirely reliable**. Re your note: From your description, it sounds like you're putting the `li` *between* the two `ul`s, which is an invalid structure. Browsers are free to try to make sense of it any way they like. If I've misunderstood, could you demonstrate what you're talking about on http://jsbin.com?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Good guess and as soon as I posted the comment I wanted to make sure. Here is the issue I was encountering, in part due to how list was being constructed in a CMS. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723372/next-not-picking-up-an-inner-ul-with-display-none-in-ie7/

Comment: @JamesPoulson: Good deal. Just so people don't get the wrong idea, shall we delete these comments?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It is fine. This can serve as "bottled" experience for other interested parties. For those reading, **next is entirely reliable** and the aforementioned issue disappears with well-formed html.