# next() not picking up an inner UL with "display: none" in IE7

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-7, html-lists

This is happening with the following markup:

```
<ul id="sideMenu" class="menuFontStyle">
<li class="category">Test</li>
<ul class="secondLevel" style="display: none;">
<li></li>
</ul>
...
```

In FF and Chrome the inner UL is being picked up but IE7 seems to be skipping to the next li. What could serve as a workaround? This is with a custom accordion script.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid; `<ul>` cannot appear directly in `<ul>`.

Comment: @SLaks Yep. This is a class case of seeing trees before forests (or vice-versa?).

Comment: Interestingly, this is exactly the same markup I came up with after reading the code at the very bottom of: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `ul` is not inside the `li` as you have closed the `li` before opening the `ul`. I don't think this is what you want.

Then, to access the `<ul>` you are far better using `.find` so it would be `$("li").find("ul")` as this will access the `<ul>` inside the `<li>` only.

```
<ul id="sideMenu" class="menuFontStyle">
    <li class="category">Test
        <ul class="secondLevel" style="display: none;">
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. This hadn't registered. Now I have to figure out how to fix the list generation in the cms :p

Answer (score 1):

That is invalid HTML, so you shouldn't be surprised at bizarre results. `ul` elements may not have other `ul` elements as direct children; they may only contain `li` elements. IE7 presumably wraps the `ul` in another `li` or something similar to make it valid.

Make your HTML valid: this will help browsers to transform it into the DOM structure that you intend and your JS coding will be a lot easier.

Comment: You're right and it makes sense. If the UL element expects  li elements then the nested UL isn't linked to any parent element and thus breaks the DOM. For once I appreciate IE7 :)